# Escaping space and equal to character

Tags: java, replaceall

I am using java and have string which could have multiple spaces and equal to "=" sign as shown below.

```
String temp = "[name='FPC:CPU']/XM chip/allocate";
```

This temp string will passed to some other program which is failing because of space and equal sign.

How can i escape space and "=" character?

My desired out put from original string

```
[name='FPC:CPU']/XM chip/allocate 

to 

[name\='FPC:CPU']/XM\ chip/allocate
```

Wondering how can i do that using `temp.replaceAll`

Comment: You need to know what the "some other program" expects and how it wants the equals sign and blank space escaped.  Please identify the other program and show the code that invokes the program passes the string to it.

Comment: If the string is escape like this, it will be fine. [name\='FPC:CPU']/XM\ chip/allocate

Comment: So you don't need to escape the space?  What part of `replaceAll` do you not understand?

Comment: I am escaping space from -> XM CHIP --to-- XM\ CHIP (note the back slash)

Comment: So what's stopping you from using `replaceAll()`?  The Javadoc is pretty clear on how to use it.

Comment: I need regular expression that can handle both "=" and " " (space) That's pretty much i need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114791/discussion-between-ammad-and-jim-garrison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be pretty straight forward.

```
System.out.println("foo bar=baz".replaceAll("([ =])" "\\\\$1"));
```

Should print this

```
foo\ bar\=baz
```

The parenthesis in the regular expression form a capturing group, and the character class `[ =]` will capture spaces and equal signs.

In the replace expression, the `$1` refers to the first capturing group. The only thing that gets a bit tricky is escaping the backslash.

Normally, in a regular expression replacement the backslash itself is an escape character. So you'd need two of them together to insert a backslash, *however* backslash is also an escape in a Java String, so to put two backslashes into a Java String (to form the regular expression escape), you must insert four backslashes. So that's how you end up with "\\$1".

Comment: putting four back slash did the trick. I was using three and getting error.